# Outlook/Gmail Mail Open Tracking

Tags: asp.net, email, encoding, html-email

At the bottom of the email content i have a tiny code

img src='https://www.......aspx?Name=David' height='1' width='1'

What it does is whenever an user open the email, it tried to download the image (if email client allow) then it loads the aspx page in the background and passing Name parameter: David as GET and in that aspx page pretty much insert David into a table.

However, this seem to be working if I open outlook via browser, rather than using outlook on windows & android app and it doesn't work in gmail via browser.

How can i make it work if an user open via outlook windows/android app

Seems like it has to do with email encoding or something?

Answer (score 0):

The email clients where this works are old, poorly designed, or misconfigured. The email clients where it doesn't work are smart enough to recognize this attempt at invading the user's privacy and block it, by not allowing remote images to load. There's not a way around it, and the entire point of not loading remote images is to keep people like you from doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: not sure if you know this, but this is exactly how mailchimp does it.